# Генератор картинки,информер Php mysql

Tags: база-данных, form, gui, изображения

Помогите создать картинку(есть шаблон картинки) в которую будет подставляться 
**переменные** данные из mysql о наличии на складе для товаров, и эта картинка будет генерироваться и сохранятся на хостинге.На сайте внизу картинки будет выводится адрес для копирования и вставки этого адреса на другой сайт....
(Возможно картинку и не сохранять ,если возможно чтобы она автоматом подставляла данные из базы.)

Comment: А с чем именно помочь-то, какие конкретно проблемы возникли при реализации описанного?

Comment: я завис с формой
<?php
      header('Content-type: image/jpeg'); 
      $jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('img.jpg'); 
      $white = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 255, 255, 255); 
      $font_path = 'E:\serv\OSPanel\domains\localhost\verdana.ttf'; 
      $text = "This is a sunset!"; 
      $text2 = "This is a sunse!"; 
      imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 75, 300, $white, $font_path, $text); 
      imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 100, 400, $white, $font_path, $text2); 
      imagejpeg($jpg_image,"1.jpg"); 
      imagedestroy($jpg_image); 
    ?>

Comment: текст к изображению добавить могу..только как прицепить его к каждому товару?